Reference class that hasn't been built yet ByteBuddy
I'm trying to generate entity classes with ByteBuddy but need to do relationship mapping so want to reference a class before I have built it.
It seems that I can't add the builder as a return value and I don't have any idea what else to try.  Is there a way to accomplish this task?

You can use DynamicType.Builder.toTypeDescription to obtain a temporary type representation, or you can use TypeDescription.Latent to directly carry some key type information.
